# Resizing a (r x c) array to (r*2 x c-1)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: day, morning and evening, where morning and evening are measurements taken.

I need to convert it into a dataframe with only day and measurement so that:

```
Day, Morning, Evening
[0, 2, 3]
```

becomes

```
Day,value
[0,2]
[0,3]
```

I can do it with a loop, but I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do it outside a loop? Especially because I will be repeating this over large(ish) datasets.

This is what I have put together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mor = np.linspace(80,85,10)
ev=np.linspace(82,87,10)

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['mor']=mor
df['ev']=ev
df.index.name='day'

x=np.zeros(mor.shape[0] * 2)*np.nan
    
for i in np.arange(0,len(mor)):
    x[2*i]=mor[i]
    x[2*i+1]=ev[i]

df_output =pd.DataFrame()
df_output['day']=np.repeat(df.index,2)
df_output['value']=x
```

Comment: Hi, have you considered posting this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) ? I believe it might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Check with `stack`

```
df_output = df.stack().reset_index(level=0)
df_output 
Out[372]: 
     day          0
mor    0  80.000000
ev     0  82.000000
mor    1  80.555556
ev     1  82.555556
mor    2  81.111111
ev     2  83.111111
mor    3  81.666667
ev     3  83.666667
mor    4  82.222222
ev     4  84.222222
mor    5  82.777778
ev     5  84.777778
mor    6  83.333333
ev     6  85.333333
mor    7  83.888889
ev     7  85.888889
mor    8  84.444444
ev     8  86.444444
mor    9  85.000000
ev     9  87.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Inspired by @gdlmx's answer, this can actually be done without using `numpy` directly:

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame({
    'day': df.index.repeat(2),
    'value': df.values.reshape(-1)
})
```

A more general solution is to replace `df.index.repeat(2)` with `df.index.repeat(df.shape[1])` for a dataframe with an arbitrary number of columns:

```
stacked_df = pd.DataFrame({
    df.index.name: df.index.repeat(df.shape[1]),
    'value': df.values.reshape(-1)
})
```

See [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/jinjiren/Answers-for-StackOverflow/blob/master/resize_dataframe.ipynb) for more details.

**Speed comparison:**
[image]

**Why is `df.stack.reset_index()` slow?**

`df.stack` itself is fast, but `reset_index` costs more time.
Evidence:
[image]

**Original answer:**
Try the following code :)

```
day = np.arange(df.size, dtype=np.int32) // 2
value = np.zeros(df.size)
value[::2] = df['mor']
value[1::2] = df['ev']
df_output2 = pd.DataFrame({'day': day, 'value': value})
```

It should be faster than `for` loop for large scale data.

Tested it with:

```
np.equal(df_output, df_output2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a memory and CPU efficient way:

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame ({
      'day':   np.repeat(df.index, df.shape[1]), 
      'value': df.values.reshape([df.size])
})
```

### Performance comparison

[image]

Comment: Hi, images of text should not be posted on stack overflow, you can post the text in a `code block` instead. Images of text are difficult to read especially on mobile devices, and are impossible to read for people with visual impairments.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But I choose to do so for Jupyter notebook codes until StackOverflow implement a better way to embed codes of notebook format (.ipynb). It's to encourage SO to improve its user experience. Please see this [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355454/6238076).

Comment: I don't understand the advantage in this case, furthermore, I can't re-use your code to do performance comparisons on my machine.